# Unable to locate merchant URL for return, issuer ACS responds with an invalid PARes or system error

Tags: virtual, point-of-sale

Unable to locate merchant URL for return, issuer ACS responds with an invalid PARes or system error

what can cause this error could you please help me

I'm trying to establish a virtual POS connection but I'm getting this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you tried multiple times and blocked. i experienced same thing and solved it by using another ip. if this doesnt work you have an error in your target url. maybe you can share your return page code